# Unable to connect to Azure SQL DB Server from Azure Kubernetes Services

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I am trying to deploy ASP .Net Core Web API 3.0 in Azure Kubernetes. My Dot Net Core Web API connects to Azure SQL Database.  Here are the configuration

connection string

```
"ConnectionString": "Server=myservername,1433;Initial Catalog=mydbname;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=userid;Password=*******;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

Deployment and Service yaml file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-web-api
  labels:
    app: my-web-api
spec:
  replicas: 2
  minReadySeconds: 45
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-web-api
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
        maxSurge: 25%
        maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-web-api
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-web-api
          image: myazureregistry/myapi:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
            - containerPort: 443
            - containerPort: 1433
      volumes:
      - name: secrets
        secret:
          secretName: secret-appsettings1
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-web-api
  labels:
    app: my-web-api
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: port-8080
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 80
    - name: port-1433
      port: 1433
      targetPort: 1433
  selector:
    app: my-web-api
```

error

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

I am new to AKS and Kubernetes.  Could some one provide solution for this one, please?

Comment: Did you allow Azure services to connect to your Azure SQL Database?

Comment: Because your cluster is in the VNET, you need to use a service endpoint to allow connection from the vnet to azure sql (https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/blog/vnet-service-endpoints-for-azure-sql-database-now-generally-available/).

Comment: Did you solved this issue? I also encounter the same issue.

Comment: Yes, I did.  There was couple of issues.
1. I have created a new service end point from kubernetes cluster to sql server as suggested by Thomas.
2. I was using wrong database name in my connection string which i noticed later.